# Streaming a CSV file to the browser in Spray

Tags: scala, csv, spray

In one part of my application I have to send a CSV file back to the browser. I have an actor that replies with a Stream[String], each element of the Stream is one line in the file that should be sent to the user.

This is what I currently have. Note that I'm currently returning `MediaType text/plain` for debugging purposes, it will be `text/csv` in the final version:

```
trait TripService extends HttpService
                          with Matchers
                          with CSVTripDefinitions {
  implicit def actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory

  implicit val executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher

  lazy val csvActor = Ridespark.system.actorSelection(s"/user/listeners/csv").resolveOne()(1000)

  implicit val stringStreamMarshaller = Marshaller.of[Stream[String]](MediaTypes.`text/plain`) { (v, ct, ctx) =>
    ctx.marshalTo(HttpEntity(ct, v.mkString("\n")))
  }

  val route = {
    get {
          path("trips" / Segment / DateSegment) { (network, date) =>
            respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`text/plain`) {
                                                            complete(askTripActor(date, network))
                                                          }
                                                }
        }
  }

  def askTripActor(date: LocalDate, network: String)
                  (implicit timeout: Timeout = Timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)): Future[Stream[String]] = {
    csvActor flatMap { actor => (actor ? GetTripsForDate(date, Some(network))).mapTo[Stream[String]] }
  }
}

class TripApi(info: AuthInfo)(implicit val actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory) extends TripService
```

My problem with this is that it will load the whole CSV into memory (due to the `mkString` in `stringStreamMarshaller`). Is there a way of not doing this, streaming the lines of the CSV as they are generated?

Comment: You should try with chunked response in spray: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-routing/advanced-topics/response-streaming/ Also as far as I know better approach is to read whole file from disk because it's slow interface and serve that. If you have seroius issue why not doing that then you should consider some kind of stream reader but it would hang the reading actor.

Comment: The CSV isn't from a file on disk. I get the data from other parts of the system and generate the CSV on the fly to send to the client. I'll have a look at chunked response. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `stringStreamMarshaller`. Using the built-in stream marshaller should already do what you want without adding the extra line-breaks. However, adding the linebreaks shouldn't be more difficult than using `streamOfStrings.map(_ + "\n")` or just adding the linebreaks when rendering the lines in the csv-actor in the first place.

Comment: @jrudolph: sorry it took so long to reply, been busy. Your answer worked great! I don't know why at some point the Stream marshaller didn't work but now it does. Could you please rewrite your comment as an answer to this question so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `stringStreamMarshaller`. Using the built-in stream marshaller should already do what you want without adding the extra line-breaks. However, adding the linebreaks shouldn't be more difficult than using `streamOfStrings.map(_ + "\n")` or just adding the linebreaks when rendering the lines in the csv-actor in the first place.